# Unable to use maven for creating a jmh benchmark

Tags: java, maven, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

By following the commands from [this official guide](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), I tried to create two benchmarks under OpenJDK 8 & 9. Yet, the results were unsuccessful as shown below. I'm a total newbie to this maven thing, so can you give me some hints to how to fix it?

## [OpenJDK 8](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8-MR3)

```
user1@debian:~$ JAVA_HOME=/home/user1/java-se-8u41-ri/ mvn archetype:generate \
>           -DinteractiveMode=false \
>           -DarchetypeGroupId=org.openjdk.jmh \
>           -DarchetypeArtifactId=jmh-java-benchmark-archetype \
>           -DgroupId=org.sample \
>           -DartifactId=test \
>           -Dversion=1.0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[WARNING] Specified archetype not found.
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjdk/jmh/jmh-java-benchmark-archetype/1.0/jmh-java-benchmark-archetype-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.603 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-10T15:01:14+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-java-benchmark-archetype:1.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

### [OpenJDK 9](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/9)

```
user1@debian:~$ JAVA_HOME=/home/user1/java-se-9-ri/jdk-9/ mvn archetype:generate \
>           -DinteractiveMode=false \
>           -DarchetypeGroupId=org.openjdk.jmh \
>           -DarchetypeArtifactId=jmh-java-benchmark-archetype \
>           -DgroupId=org.sample \
>           -DartifactId=test \
>           -Dversion=1.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[WARNING] Specified archetype not found.
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/openjdk/jmh/jmh-java-benchmark-archetype/1.0/jmh-java-benchmark-archetype-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.732 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-10T15:08:01+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-java-benchmark-archetype:1.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Where is your POM??

Comment: You have not included a POM in your project so maven is not able to resolve the archetype , I had previously made a project on JMH, https://github.com/vishwaratna/Benchmarking-in-JAVA-methods-using-JMH if you want then you can have a look at it.

Comment: @VishwaRatna Thanks. I just thought following the official JMH guide would suffice. But, obviously, it needs some work to be done beforehand. I'll take a look at the link, and see if I can make it work.

Comment: A complete starter from my point of view: https://dzone.com/articles/measuring-performance-of-your-methods-using-jmh-in

Comment: You should use not version one for the archetype better use the most recent version https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.openjdk.jmh/jmh-java-benchmark-archetype/1.23/maven-archetype

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @RobertScholte Under the default network namespace, I'm not.

Comment: Normally Maven starts with `Downloading ....` followed by `Downloaded ....` in case it needs to download jars. Here it stops after the first, which indicated a network issue. The URL is valid, that's not the issue.